# ebpf: how to use BPF_FUNC_trace_printk in eBPF assembly program

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I have a small `socket filter` type eBPF program, where I'm trying to print a protocol value read from `__sk_buff` context:

```
struct bpf_insn prog[] = {
   BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_6, BPF_REG_1),
   BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_6, offsetof(struct __sk_buff, protocol)),
   BPF_STX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_10, BPF_REG_0, -4),
   BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_1, BPF_REG_10),
   BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_1, -4),
   BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_2, 4),
   BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_JMP | BPF_CALL, 0, 0, 0, BPF_FUNC_trace_printk),
   BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),
   BPF_EXIT_INSN(),
};
```

...

I create a raw `socket` and bind it to the `lo` interface, then `setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_BPF, ...)`. It compiles and loads with no problems, however whenever I `ping 127.0.0.1` I never see traces in the `trace_pipe`.

So, to make sure that it `BPF_FUNC_trace_printk` actually can work, I changed it so that it prints a static string on the stack, and it does print on every packet hitting the loopback.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Read the friendly manual :)

I don't believe you are calling the `bpf_trace_printk()` helper correctly (`BPF_FUNC_trace_prink` is just an integer, by the way). Its signature, commented in the kernel UAPI header bpf.h or in [the `bpf-helpers` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html), is as follows:

```c
long bpf_trace_printk(const char *fmt, u32 fmt_size, ...);
```

This means that the first argument must be a constant, null-terminated format string, not an integer like you do.

#### What does clang do?

I understand you are attaching your eBPF programs to sockets and cannot compile the whole program from C. However, why not compile *that specific part* as a generic networking eBPF program to see what the bytecode should look like? Let's write the C code:

```c
#include <linux/bpf.h>

static long (*bpf_trace_printk)(const char *fmt, __u32 fmt_size, ...) = (void *) BPF_FUNC_trace_printk;

int printk_proto(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    char fmt[] = "%d\n";

    bpf_trace_printk(fmt, sizeof(fmt), skb->protocol);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile to an object file. For the record this would not load, unless we provide both a valid licence string (because `bpf_trace_prink()` needs a GPL-compatible program) and a compatible program type at load time. But it does not matter in our case, we just want to look at the generated instructions.

```
$ clang -O2 -g -emit-llvm -c prink_protocol.c  -o - | \
        llc -march=bpf -mcpu=probe -filetype=obj -o prink_protocol.o
```

Dump the bytecode:

```
$ llvm-objdump -d prink_protocol.o 

prink_protocol.o:       file format elf64-bpf


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <printk_proto>:
       0:       b4 02 00 00 25 64 0a 00 w2 = 680997
       1:       63 2a fc ff 00 00 00 00 *(u32 *)(r10 - 4) = r2
       2:       61 13 10 00 00 00 00 00 r3 = *(u32 *)(r1 + 16)
       3:       bf a1 00 00 00 00 00 00 r1 = r10
       4:       07 01 00 00 fc ff ff ff r1 += -4
       5:       b4 02 00 00 04 00 00 00 w2 = 4
       6:       85 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 call 6
       7:       b4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 w0 = 0
       8:       95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 exit
```

We can see that on the first two instructions, the program writes the format string (in little endian) onto the stack: `680997` is `0x000a6425`, `\0\nd%`. `r2` still contains the length for the format string. The protocol value is stored in `r3`, the third argument for the call to `bpf_trace_prink()`.